# how to make an horizontal enquiry form which should be fixed till i scroll to the bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a horizontal enquiry form that shows up after the front page banner. I wish to make it fix and scrollable till the end of the page. How can I make it happen? It should be responsive as well.

**HTML**

```
<div id="hide" class="search-form">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="myForm" action="form.php" method="post" class="row" onSubmit="alert('Thank you for your feedback.');" > 

      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4" "required"="">
        <label>Name*</label>
        <div class="name">
        <input name="name" required="" type="text" placeholder="Full Name ">
        </div>
     </div>

      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4" "required"="">
        <label>Email*</label>
        <div class="email_id">
          <input name="email" required="" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-\_.]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,5}$" type="text" placeholder="email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4" "required"="">
        <label>Mobile No*</label>
         <div class="mobileno">
            <input name="mobileno" required="" pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" type="text" placeholder="Mobile no">
         </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4" "required"="">
        <label>Interested in</label>
        <div class="selector">
        <select class="full-width" name="project">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select a Project</option>    
            <option value="La Colina">La Colina</option>
            <option value="Royal Casa">Royal Casa</option>
            <option value="Country Side">Country Side</option>
         </select><span class="custom-select full-width">Project</span>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <label>Budget</label><div class="selector">
          <select class="full-width" name="budget">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select a Budget</option>    
            <option value="500000-1000000">500000-1000000</option>
            <option value="1000000-1500000">1000000-1500000</option>
            <option value="1500000-2000000">1500000-2000000</option>
            <option value="2000000 and above">2000000 and above</option>
          </select><span class="custom-select full-width">Budget</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
        <button class="sub" type="submit" style="search-form">Enquire Now</button>
        <span id="result"></span>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.search-form {
  margin: -63px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  display: block;
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Comment: `style="search-form"` is invalid. The "style" attribute can only contain CSS rules, not class names. add "search-form" to the list in the "class" attribute of that element. It's going to be a very wide button though - are you sure that class is not meant to be applied to the whole form?